# Vue SPA - PhantomJS works successfully, but Fetch As Google shows blank

Tags: vue.js, phantomjs, seo, single-page-application

My team has built a SPA using Vue (https://tutorismhk.com/).
When working on the SEO, we find that Fetch As Google failed to render the page (showing blank page in the preview). There is no error message shown.

We have tested with PhantomJS v2.1.1 - using it to render the above URL from our local machine and snap the screen into an image. It just worked well.

Any idea about how we can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

We found a workaround after some trial and error. There are two problems for our application.

1. We manually installed the latest babel-polyfill. I guess it causes some incompatible problem.
2. It seems like after upgrading @vue/cli-plugin-babel to v3.4.0, it starts to have some problem with other dependencies we have (in our case, vue-izitoast v1.1.2).

After uninstalling babel-polyfill and downgrading @vue/cli-plugin-babel to v3.3.0, Fetch As Google succeeds rendering our page.